# How come the preloader doesn't disappear sometimes?

Tags: jquery

*(Please note: I have one similar question active - but it's completely different as to the problem)*

[Please see here for an example](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/verzia4/)

As you click through the left navigation menu, notice that every other click the preloader doesn't disappear... I don't know why.

Here's the code I have:

I left some comments to make it easier to understand. Thanks a lot everyobody :)

```
var pageToLoad = '';
switch( this.id ){
        case 'events_map_button':
      $('#huge-loader').fadeIn('fast', function() {  //show preloader
      pageToLoad = 'partytool.html';                 //define page to load
      });
      break;
        case 'event_search_tool_button':
      $('#huge-loader').fadeIn('fast', function() {
      pageToLoad = 'partytool.html';
          configureEvents();
      });
      break;
        case 'party_photos_button':
      $('#huge-loader').fadeIn('fast', function() {
      pageToLoad = 'partyphotos.html';
      });
      break;
        case 'taxi_finder_button':
      $('#huge-loader').fadeIn('fast', function() {
      pageToLoad = 'taxiservices.html';
      });
      break;
        case 'weather_forecast_button':
      $('#huge-loader').fadeIn('fast', function() {
      pageToLoad = 'weatherforecast.html';
      });
      break;
        case 'contact_button':
      $('#huge-loader').fadeIn('fast', function() {
      pageToLoad = 'contact.html';
      });
      break;
}
if( '' !== pageToLoad ){                                //if the variable isn't empty
   $('#right-content').load( pageToLoad, function() {   //load the page
   $("#huge-loader").fadeOut("slow");                   //then hide preloader
   });
}
```

Comment: Every other click, your page load request doesn't fire.

Comment: From the looks of it, `this.id` isn't what you think it is, at least not on every other click. `console.debug(this)` near your switch, and you might be surprised at what turns up.

Comment: Why are you setting `pageToLoad` in the effect callback? Surely you want to set that straight away.

Comment: Thanks to both of you. I'm confused about Frederick's answer though, is there something wrong with the way the code is now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are hitting the bottom portion of the code before the pageToLoad is set.
Put that bottom portion in each of your fadeout complete functions.

Comment: Are you suggesting that I put this `$('#right-content').load( pageToLoad` after the fadeout complete function? If I do that, then the content will be loaded after the loading disappears.

Comment: #huge-loader->fadeIn(when done with fadein)->#right-content->load(when done with load)->#huge-fader->fadeout()
like
----
`case 'party_photos_button':
      $('#huge-loader').fadeIn('fast', function() {
        $('#right-content').load( 'partyphotos.html', function() {
          $("#huge-loader").fadeOut("slow");
        });
      });
`

Comment: Hi Mark, thanks for your additional comment since. The code was working for me great until I tried to add more images to preload which caused some issues in IE. Here's my newer question surrounding that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8843283/jquery-preloader-stopped-working-ie