# Jquery Preloader stopped working IE

Tags: jquery

Edit:

I have a multiple image preloading script that I'm having problems with on IE, and people have mentioned that the reason is because of caching. I'm currently exporing any alternatives that would allow me to:

- Preload a *predefined* set of images because my content is loaded via ajax
- Be allowed to set those images as css backgrounds

[Here's the demo site](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/verzia4/)
(works in all browsers except IE)

And here's what the code looks like right now:

*It looks long, however it's mostly just repeat code*

```
    var  src1 = 'img/map_bg_1680.jpg'
    , $img1 = $( '<img src="' + src1 + '">' );

    var  src2 = 'img/menu-background.png'
    , $img2 = $( '<img src="' + src2 + '">' );

    var  src3 = 'img/button01.png'
    , $img3 = $( '<img src="' + src3 + '">' );

    var  src4 = 'img/button02.png'
    , $img4 = $( '<img src="' + src4 + '">' );

    var  src5 = 'img/button03.png'
    , $img5 = $( '<img src="' + src5 + '">' );

    var  src6 = 'img/button04.png'
    , $img6 = $( '<img src="' + src6 + '">' );

    var  src7 = 'img/button05.png'
    , $img7 = $( '<img src="' + src7 + '">' );

    var  src8 = 'img/button06.png'
    , $img8 = $( '<img src="' + src8 + '">' );

    var  src9 = 'img/all_events_button.png'
    , $img9 = $( '<img src="' + src9 + '">' );

    var  src10 = 'img/all_venues_button.png'
    , $img10 = $( '<img src="' + src10 + '">' );

    var  src11 = 'img/event_finder_button.png'
    , $img11 = $( '<img src="' + src11 + '">' );

    var  src12 = 'img/today-button.png'
    , $img12 = $( '<img src="' + src12 + '">' );

    var  src13 = 'img/tomorrow-button.png'
    , $img13 = $( '<img src="' + src13 + '">' );

    var  src14 = 'img/some-other-day-button.png'
    , $img14 = $( '<img src="' + src14 + '">' );

    var  src15 = 'img/choose-button.png'
    , $img15 = $( '<img src="' + src15 + '">' );

    var  src16 = 'img/newsearch-button.png'
    , $img16 = $( '<img src="' + src16 + '">' );

    var  src17 = 'img/showresults-button.png'
    , $img17 = $( '<img src="' + src17 + '">' );

$(document).ready(function() { 

    $(".ajax").colorbox();




var img1loaded = false
  , img2loaded = false
  , img3loaded = false
  , img4loaded = false
  , img5loaded = false
  , img6loaded = false
  , img7loaded = false
  , img8loaded = false
  , img9loaded = false
  , img10loaded = false
  , img11loaded = false
  , img12loaded = false
  , img13loaded = false
  , img14loaded = false
  , img15loaded = false
  , img16loaded = false
  , img17loaded = false;

$img1.bind( 'load', function(){
    img1loaded = true;
    finish();
} );

$img2.bind( 'load', function(){
    img2loaded = true;
    finish();
} );

$img3.bind( 'load', function(){
    img3loaded = true;
    finish();
} );

$img4.bind( 'load', function(){
    img4loaded = true;
    finish();
} );

$img5.bind( 'load', function(){
    img5loaded = true;
    finish();
} );

$img6.bind( 'load', function(){
    img6loaded = true;
    finish();
} );

$img7.bind( 'load', function(){
    img7loaded = true;
    finish();
} );

$img8.bind( 'load', function(){
    img8loaded = true;
    finish();
} );

$img9.bind( 'load', function(){
    img9loaded = true;
    finish();
} );

$img10.bind( 'load', function(){
    img10loaded = true;
    finish();
} );

$img11.bind( 'load', function(){
    img11loaded = true;
    finish();
} );

$img12.bind( 'load', function(){
    img12loaded = true;
    finish();
} );

$img13.bind( 'load', function(){
    img13loaded = true;
    finish();
} );

$img14.bind( 'load', function(){
    img14loaded = true;
    finish();
} );

$img15.bind( 'load', function(){
    img15loaded = true;
    finish();
} );

$img16.bind( 'load', function(){
    img16loaded = true;
    finish();
} );

$img17.bind( 'load', function(){
    img17loaded = true;
    finish();
} );

function finish(){
    if( !img1loaded || !img2loaded || !img3loaded || !img4loaded || !img5loaded || !img6loaded || !img7loaded || !img8loaded || !img9loaded || !img10loaded || !img11loaded || !img12loaded || !img13loaded || !img14loaded || !img15loaded || !img16loaded || !img17loaded ){ return; }
            jQuery('#main-content-fiftyfive').load('index2.html', function() {
                $( '#bgDiv' ).css( 'background-image', 'url( ' + src1 + ')' ); 
                jQuery( '#viewport-container' ).css( 'background-image', 'url( ' + src2 + ')' );
                jQuery( '#events_map_button' ).css( 'background-image', 'url( ' + src3 + ')' );
                jQuery( '#event_search_tool_button' ).css( 'background-image', 'url( ' + src4 + ')' );
                jQuery( '#party_photos_button' ).css( 'background-image', 'url( ' + src5 + ')' );
                jQuery( '#taxi_finder_button' ).css( 'background-image', 'url( ' + src6 + ')' );
                jQuery( '#weather_forecast_button' ).css( 'background-image', 'url( ' + src7 + ')' );
                jQuery( '#contact_button' ).css( 'background-image', 'url( ' + src8 + ')' );

                $('#right-content').load('partytool.html', function() {

                    setPartyToolsButtons();

                    $('#whole-ajax-content-one').load('events.html', function() {
                        setDayChooserButtons();
                        $( '.preloader' ).fadeOut('slow', function() {
                            $( '#bgDiv' ).fadeIn('slow', function() {
                                $( '#table-holder' ).fadeIn('slow', function() {
                                initialConfig();
                        });
                    });
                });
            });     
        });
    });
}
if( $img1[0].width ){ $img1.trigger( 'load' ); }
if( $img2[0].width ){ $img2.trigger( 'load' ); }
if( $img3[0].width ){ $img3.trigger( 'load' ); }
if( $img4[0].width ){ $img4.trigger( 'load' ); }
if( $img5[0].width ){ $img5.trigger( 'load' ); }
if( $img6[0].width ){ $img6.trigger( 'load' ); }
if( $img7[0].width ){ $img7.trigger( 'load' ); }
if( $img8[0].width ){ $img8.trigger( 'load' ); }
if( $img9[0].width ){ $img9.trigger( 'load' ); }
if( $img10[0].width ){ $img10.trigger( 'load' ); }
if( $img11[0].width ){ $img11.trigger( 'load' ); }
if( $img12[0].width ){ $img12.trigger( 'load' ); }
if( $img13[0].width ){ $img13.trigger( 'load' ); }
if( $img14[0].width ){ $img14.trigger( 'load' ); }
if( $img15[0].width ){ $img15.trigger( 'load' ); }
if( $img16[0].width ){ $img16.trigger( 'load' ); }
if( $img17[0].width ){ $img17.trigger( 'load' ); }


});
```

I appreciate everyone's input, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is basically your app, the loading of images + html rewritten to use jQuery's Deferred Object

http://jsfiddle.net/roberkules/hH8YN/ -> works for me on IE8, FF9 & Chrome16

the main part of the script is:

```
var images = {
    'bg': 'img/map_bg_1680.jpg'
    // ...
};

var defer = $.Deferred();

var promise = $.when.apply($, $.merge([defer.promise()], $.map(images, function(value, key) {
    var d = $.Deferred(),
        img = $('<img />').attr('src', root_path + value).load(function() {
            console.log('loaded img', key, value);
            d.resolve();
        }).get(0);

    if (img.complete) {
        console.log('cached img', key, value);
        d.resolve();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            if (!d.isResolved()) {
                console.log('timeout img', key, value);
                d.resolve();
            }
        }, 15000); // e.g.: 15 seconds timeout
    }

    return d.promise();
})));

$(function() {
    $.get('index2.html', function(data) {
        console.log('loaded html', 'index2.html');
        $('#main-content-fiftyfive').html(data.responseText || data);
        defer.resolve();
    });

    promise.done(function() {
        // index2.html + images loaded...
    }
});
```

(had to use some minor hacks, just because the content is on your host, so obviously you can remove those hacks for your page)

Comment: Thank you so much Roberkules :)))! Sorry it took me so long but I was away. Can I, however bother you for a minute more please? I did some editing as you suggested and the result is that nothing is loaded into `#main-content-fiftyfive`, yet I have no errors and all console messages show. [This is what it looks like now](http://nightlifebratislava.com/demos/verzia6/) And [here's](http://jsfiddle.net/pufamuf/P9NnK/) the code in a more readable format :)

Comment: can you try in all $.get(...function() callbacks to use e.g.: `$('#main-content-fiftyfive').html(data.responseText || data);`

Comment: Thank you!!! :)) I could have never achieved this without your help! Thanks so much :))

Comment: you're welcome. I'll add one more small addition - a timeout in the image loading... because you don't want to break everything just if 1 image doesn't (pre)load in time?! so I'll add a timeout. never been to bratislava yet, but if i will go there (anyways not so far away from vienna), I'll use your guide :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead...

```
$(function() {
    var imgCount = $("img").length;
    $("img").one("load", function() {
        imgCount--;
        if (imgCount == 0) finish();
    }).each(function() {
        if (this.complete) $(this).load();
    });
});
```

Basically, on document.ready it gets a count of all images and then waits till they've all loaded before firing the finish() method.  Don't worry about the boolean values in finish() - just comment that out. Also comment out all your .load() handlers.

This does take caching into account, with the (this.complete) check.  I've used this extensively and it's proved very useful.

Comment: Thank you Archer, but I'm loading a lot of content via ajax after the page is loaded, and all of the images are basically css backgrounds. Are those loaded as well?

Answer (score 1):

Your way of pre-loading images doesn't take into account the image being cached. If it is cached, it may not always trigger the load event.

Here is a plugin that preloads images.

https://github.com/tentonaxe/jQuery-preloadImages

Comment: Hi Kevin, does this also preload css backgrounds? What about content that is loaded via ajax after the original page is loaded?

Comment: it can, you would have to pass the img url to the core method `$.preloadImages(["url1","url2"],callbackfn)` I'm working on a 2.0.0 atm, I'll think about adding css background functionality.

Comment: Here's a sneak peek at v2 with deferred support: http://jsfiddle.net/Tentonaxe/9d7Vb/

Comment: Hi Kevin, I finally got to your code (v1.0), however it doesn't load for me (Firefox 6.0.2 XP). The downloaded version is still showing 'loading' after several minutes (and I have a fiber optic connection) and the online version demo also shows nothing. The jsFiddle works for me so I might play with it as well and see if I come to something.